# MVVM approach, ViewModel properties vs Model properties

Tags: model, architecture, viewmodel

Currently working on a offline-first Xamarin sale's force application, I have a question concerning the MVVM architecture: my application currently have 4 shared solutions: Abstractions, Core, DAL and UI (and of course, Platform/iOS and Platform/Droid). Each solution is pretty self-explanatory - Abstractions holds the interfaces, Core contains all the business logic (Events, Models, ViewModel, etc.), DAL all the DB entities (since I'm working with Realm, I'm not using repositories, just the plain realm instance in each VM) and, finally, the UI, which holds, huh, all the UI (duh).

Well, so, back to the question... currenly, let's say I have this:

Order : RealmObject -> When OrderViewModel is loaded, it calls _realm.All and subscribes for notifications. Each RealmObject is then converted in an OrderModel and loaded into an ObservableCollection AllProducts. This works pretty well.

Now, in my AddOrderPage, I have a form containing the essential data for making an order. The question is: should my AddOrderPageViewModel have each OrderModel property in itself or should I simply use an OrderModel property? Basically, this:

```
public class OrderViewModel {

    OrderModel _order;

    public OrderModel Order {
        get => _order;
        set {
            _order = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Order));
        }
    }

    public SaveOrder()
    {
        // do validation
        _realm.Save(_order);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class OrderViewModel {

    decimal _amount;

    public decimal Amount (...)

    decimal _price;

    public decimal Price (...)

    (...)

    public SaveOrder()
    {
        var order = new Order { ..., _amount, _price);
        // do validation
        _realm.Save(order);
    }
}
```

It might sound a dumb question at first sight, but my main concern is: should I raise propertyChanges from model? Doesn't it hurts the POCO principles? For instance, if OrderModel contains an ObservableCollection (or even a List) _orderDetails and, when it's updated, it also should raise a propertyChanged on a TotalPrice, is it correct to be done at Model?

Comment: I would advise you implement a ViewModelBase that can call the INotifyProperty methods. Also if you are working on a large app you should probably think about implementing an MVVM helper. I use & recommend prism, they have a ton of great examples and videos showing you the best practises for architecting mvvm xamarin apps!

Comment: Hi there, @Axemasta! Actually, this was just a sample code. Coincidently, I'm using Prism, so, all methods are using SetProperty ;)

Comment: Hi @Fábio glad to hear you are using an MVVM helper. If you go over to prism's youtube channel (I wont link incase links die) they have a video called "Using Delegate Commands". This video shows you the best practises for using the getters/setters of a view model. You can save your entities in the setter, but it can get very messy and you need to null check them if you want to do this otherwise you may encounter problems destroying the viewmodel  (bindings will update when their value becomes null). Prism has you covered though, their video's, docs & OS contributions are great, go follow them!

Comment: Hey, @Axemasta, thanks for the tip. I've taken a time to watch the video and it was really useful, I'm planning to watch more of them as soon as possible.

Comment: Prism actually have a private slack group which you can get access to by pledging something like $1 on their patreon. It is incredibly useful and the gusy in the group (not just the maintainers) are incredibly knowledgeable and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

the first one is more suited to MVVM as the model shouldn't be doing any logic. You are correct that the OrderModel should not have the propertyChanges method - that would be in the view model. The model should really only have the properties and a constructor. Any further logic, like the propertyChanged would be in a view model that is accessing the model